# Android Studio is not Running After Disabling Dart and Kotlin plugins

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, dart

I tried to Disable **Dart** and **Kotlin** plugin from setting of Android Studio:

[image]

and after restarting its throwing error :

> Missing essential plugin: `org.jetbrains.android` 
> please reinstall Android studio from scratch

is there any way to solve this problem without reinstalling?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Locate the `disabled_plugins.txt` file

**Windows**:
`C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioX.X\disabled_plugins.txt`

**macOS**

`~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudioX.X/studio.vmoptions`

**Linux**

`~/.config/Google/AndroidStudioX.X/studio64.vmoptions`

Where X.X is your android studio version.

Delete the file or the offending line within the file.

Comment: Or failing that, you can just delete that file.

Comment: I founded the file, and there was the *Dart* and *Kotlin*, and after deletion of it the android studio run successfully.